# Correct usage of "must have to"

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

The construction 'must have to' is used in this sentence:

> Oh, it is locked. We must have to have the key to open it.

Is this correct? Is there a better alternative phrasing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, *must* and *have to* mean the same thing, so this is redundant.

> <sup>✲</sup>Oh, it's locked. We have to have to have the key to open it.

The only situation in which you would use both expressions is if you are using *must* in the 'epistemic' sense of (approximately) "appears very probable that" or "is my confident inference that"

> Oh, it's locked. I conclude that we have to have the key to open it.

But that's really semantic overkill for conversational usage! I think most people would say simply:

> Oh, it's locked. We need the key.

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*

Answer (score 0):

Its a kind of deduction 
When we say:

> oh,we are starving,we must have to stop to eat something.

it means that **we are very likely to be forced** to stop

Comment: Yeah, and it is, as @stoneyb put it, an overkill to use such a long term. The simpler, the better.